# AngularJS - Apply a class onclick and keep it applied, or remove when clicked again

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am applying a class on onclick to my custom element, and I want to keep it applied. Like there are bunch of `<event>` elements, and when I click on some other element, the previous element loses that `selected` class. That is I cannot get it to apply the `selected` class to more than one class at a time.

Here is my view code:

```
<event class="event" ng-repeat="event in events" event="{{ event }}"
       ng-class="{'selected' : $index == selected}"
       ng-click="selectEvent($index, event)">
    {{ event }}
</event>
```

And here is my controller

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selectEvent = function($index, event) {
        $scope.selected = $index;
        console.log(event);
    }
});
```

Additionally, I would also like for the class to be removed to when the particular `<event>` is clicked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only got one piece of data (`$scope.selected`) tracking selection. Every time a new element is clicked, the previous selection is overwritten.

If you want each event to have a separate selected/not-selected state, you have to create a data structure that allows that.

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cmacrander/T6JFX/) fiddle, I defined events as:

```
    $scope.events = [
        {name: 'event1', selected: false},
        {name: 'event2', selected: false},
        {name: 'event3', selected: false}
    ];
```

And I think it works as you intended.